# How do I add src and class to a Html.img in Elm?

Tags: html, image, class, elm, src

I have an `Html.img` in Elm and I would like to add `src` and a `class` to it. How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Html exposing (img, div)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class, src)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ img [ class "my-img", src "https://loremflickr.com/320/240" ] []
        ]
```

View a live example [here](https://ellie-app.com/cTvM5w468nfa1)!

Or read more about [Html.Attributes](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Attributes).